# Old-style figures: Use in references/brackets (e.g. to equations, bibliography) or not?

Tags: punctuation, typography, oldstylenums

In my documents I usually use old-style figures for "non-mathematical" numbers. By this I mean for example dates, page numbers, telephone numbers and the like. For tables, results of equations etc. I generally use lining figures, to distinguish them from the other numbers and to make it easier to recognize the magnitude. I usually do this with the `\num{}` command provided by `siunitx`.

Using OSF by default sometimes looks a bit odd, though. Consider for instance the case of putting an OSF between brackets for referencing. Here are two examples:

[image: Properly filled brackets and odd OSF.]
[image: Properly filled brackets and odd OSF.]

As you can see, lining figures nicely fill up the brackets, they seem to fit into them. The OSF (2) and (3) look odd though, for example there is a dissymmetry in the (3) because it stretches below the bracket and there is a space above it.

This is even more so the case with the [189] in the second example. The 9 even extents until below the bracket!

My specific question is now how to handle this case. Is what I have shown here fine? Should I use OSFs for my main text, but then lining figures in such brackets? If yes, would this not look inconsistent? Should I not use OSFs at all? Or is there  another fix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Knuth writes, in an [TUGboat article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb10-1/tb23knut.pdf) titled *Typesetting Concrete Mathematics* (which uses Euler for math):

> … This experience proved to be worthwhile, because it taught me that there is a
>   useful and meaningful distinction between text numerals and mathematical
>   numerals. Text numerals are used in contexts like ‘1776’ and ‘Chapter 5’ and
>   ‘41 ways’, where the numbers are essentially part of the English language;
>   mathematical numerals, by contrast, are used in contexts like ‘the greatest
>   common divisor of 12 and 18 is 6’, where the numbers are part of the
>   mathematics.

And later:

> Equation numbers presented us with one of the most perplexing design questions.
>   Should those numbers be typeset in Euler or cast in Concrete? After several
>   experiments we hit on a solution that must be right, because it seems so
>   obvious in retrospect: We decided to set equation numbers in an “oldstyle”
>   variant of Concrete Roman, using the digits ‘0123456789’. The result – e.g.,
>   '(3.14)' – was surprisingly effective.

(Note: the numbers in the above quote are in “oldstyle” in the original; I’m not sure how to get them here)