# mathpazo old-style figures and eulervm: I want lining figures in math

Tags: math-mode, oldstylenums, mathpazo, eulervm

I would like to use Palatino with small caps and old-style figures
for text and Euler with euler-digits for math.

If I use  `\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}`  *without eulervm* I get
old-style figures in text mode and lining figures in math mode, which
is what I want.

If I add  `\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}`  I get old-style figures
in text mode, euler digits for  `\mathnormal`  and  `\mathbold`  but also
pazo **old-style figures** for  `\mathrm` ,  `\mathit` , and  `\mathbf` , which
I do NOT want.

It seems eulervm 'switch back' to text font (with old-style figures)
for  `\mathrm` ,  `\mathit` , and  `\mathbf` .  I'd like it to 'switch back'
to *lining figures* font.

How could I get

- pazo's old-style figures in text mode,
- euler-digits in math mode for  `\mathnormal` ,
- pazo's *lining figures* in mathmode for  `\mathrm` ,  `\mathit` , and  `\mathbf`  ?

I really do not want old-style figures in math mode.

%%%% ECM mathpazo osf and eulervm

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% mathpazo osf alone gives old-style figures in text mode
% and lining figures in math mode  :-)
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
% eulervm 'switch back' to pazo's old-style figres  :-(
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Mathpazo text: 1234567890 old-style figures OK.

Euler math with euler-digits:
\begin{align*}
1234567890  \qquad &\text{mathnormal: euler-digits OK}  \\
\mathrm{1234567890}  \qquad &\text{mathrm: pazo old-style figures KO}  \\
\mathit{1234567890}  \qquad &\text{mathit: pazo old-style figures italic KO}  \\
\mathbf{1234567890}  \qquad &\text{mathbf: pazo old-style figures bold KO}  \\
\mathbold{1234567890}  \qquad &\text{mathbold: euler-digits OK}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

%%%% End of ECM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use "lining figures" fonts for the math alphabets: add the following lines before `\begin{document}`:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{\encodingdefault}{ppl}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{\encodingdefault}{ppl}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}{\encodingdefault}{ppl}{m}{it}
```

so that the alphabets chosen by `\mathrm`, `\mathbf` and `\mathit` will use the family `ppl` rather than the default family.

### Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{\encodingdefault}{ppl}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{\encodingdefault}{ppl}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}{\encodingdefault}{ppl}{m}{it}

\begin{document}

Mathpazo text: 1234567890 old-style figures OK.

Euler math with euler-digits:
\begin{align*}
1234567890  \qquad &\text{mathnormal: euler-digits OK}  \\
\mathrm{1234567890}  \qquad &\text{mathrm: pazo old-style figures OK}  \\
\mathit{1234567890}  \qquad &\text{mathit: pazo old-style figures italic OK}  \\
\mathbf{1234567890}  \qquad &\text{mathbf: pazo old-style figures bold OK}  \\
\mathbold{1234567890}  \qquad &\text{mathbold: euler-digits OK}
\end{align*}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What would need to be done, additionally, to instruct LaTeX to use lining-style numerals for equation numbers? I know this isn't a topic the OP has asked for explicitly, but as it seems to come up regularly in TeX.SE, the subject may be worth addressing here.

Comment: Equation numbers should be in the text mode font, so OSF if that's the choice.

Comment: Than you egreg, it does exactly what I want.  IIUC "operators" is the equivalent to "mathrm"?  @Mico actually OSF for equation numbers is fine.  I was convinced by http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50843/13854

Comment: @XavierScheuer -- For a related answer on the topic of using oldstyle numbers for equation numbers, you may also want to check out http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38827/5001 (shameless-self-advertising warning!), especially the sentences in the quote from Knuth following the second `[...]` particle. Please note that I wasn't advocating the use of lining numerals for equation numbers in a paper that uses oldstyle numerals. It's just a topic that comes up frequently on TeX.SE, and I thought it might be good to have the master, i.e., @egreg, explain to us how one might achieve such an effect.

Comment: Is there any reason the `fontenc` package is loaded _after_ `mathpazo` and `eulervm` in this piece of code?

Comment: @gigabytes No, it just was there in the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simpler solution would be to instruct latex to use palatino directly, instead of using only little of what mathpazo has to offer?

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pplj} %palatino with old style numbers in text
\linespread{1.05} % Palatino needs more leading (space between lines)
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm} %keep nicer euler digits
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %set to newer output font encoding
```