# Is there any difference between math mode and text mode for numbers?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, numbering, amsmath, best-practices

Take the sentence: "The answer is 42". Is there any difference between

```
The answer is $42$.
```

and

```
The answer is 42.
```

In the final PDF I cannot see any difference. Does it make a difference whether I use math mode or text mode for numbers? If so: What shall I use?

Comment: There can be a difference, depending on the fonts you are using.  I would use math mode for maths and text mode for numbers that occasionally appear in the middle of your text.

Comment: I now found http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57370/should-running-text-numbers-be-typeset-with-math-mode which already answered my question... Would be great if someone may mark this question as a duplicate...